# Automatically cast objects to ObjectId in Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I have a mongoose model looking like this:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}
});
```

In angular I post an item to my server but mongoose is complaining it can not cast an object to an id because the Item object contains a category object while it is expecting an idea. Now I can replace the category field with the category._id and solve the problem. But I wonder if there is a way to make mongoose handle this automatically? If not what is good practice?

Answer (score 0):

At work we just use the _id field. I think thats best practice because it ensures that Mongoose is referencing the right object.

If you want it to have the category object instead of the id when retrieving it from the database, you can use the populate option: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I know but when you have your object (at client side) with all fields populated, it's bothersome having to replace all its fields with the ids at server side.